# Обновление связей при кешировании Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, кэширование

Есть две модели: модель **Post** и модель **Author**.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Кеширование фрагментов сделано так:

```
- posts.each do |post| do
  - cache post do
    #много кода

    - cache post.author do
      = post.author.username
```

Проблема в том, что при обновлении Author кеш не обновляется. То есть, пользователю отображаются устаревшие данные *post.author.username*.

Пробовал добавлять **touch: true** к belongs_to :author — безрезультатно. **Гем 'cache_digests'** подключен и работает. Обновляется *post.author.username*, только если обновишь сам Post.

Что делать и почему не работает как надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, `touch` у `belongs_to :author` сделает наоборот: если изменится пост, он бампнет `updated_at` его автора. Собстна, можно так и сделать (см. ниже), но могут быть решения и попроще:

---

#### А может, нафиг всё это?

**Разделите** представления поста и его автора. Как-то так:

```
# Заголовок поста                                   | Имя автора
                                                    | Ранг автора
Ut pellentesque lacus nunc, consequat sollicitudin  | Активность автора
tortor blandit volutpat. Aenean pellentesque        | Что-то ещё
hendrerit congue. Morbi pharetra sapien in purus    |
ultrices, quis tempus odio imperdiet. Phasellus ut  |
molestie risus. Nam pellentesque sed arcu vitae     |
pretium.                                            |
```

...чтобы ни один из этих двух не лежат внутри другого. Тогда эта проблема просто не возникнет.

---

#### Нет, не нафиг!

Хорошо, тогда можно сделать кэш-ключ по двум моделям сразу:

```rb
cache [post, post.author] do
  # Пост
end
```

...так объект автора должен быть загружен, чтобы вычислить кэш-ключ.

Альтернативный способ сделать это же, это доопределить кэш-ключ в модели поста:

```
def cache_key
  "#{super}-#{author.cache_key}"
end
```

...правда, при этом посты будут постоянно тянуть своих авторов при любой попытке вытянуться из кэша. Хотя, может, вам это и надо?

---

#### А в самой модели никак?

Ну, можно и в самой модели. Собственно, можно закэшировать `author.updated_at` внутри `Post#cached_at`. Добавьте соответствующую колонку в пост, а автору сделайте вот это:

```
after_save do
  posts.update_all(cached_at: updated_at) # Осторожно, никаких валидаций и коллбэков!
end
```

...и, соответственно, доопределите кэш-ключ поста:

```
def cache_key
  "#{super}-#{cached_at}"
end
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, решил сделать способом "Нет, не нафиг!" и все работает.